# JavaMail SMTPTransport.isConnected() very slow with Exchange server

Tags: performance, jakarta-mail

I have a mail daemon to send email notification using JavaMail (1.4.5) with SMTP. It is suggested to use the instance method `sendMessage()` instead of the static `Transport.send()`. So I am testing the connection with `isConnected()` before calling `sendMessage()`. It works fine on my home computer with my ISP's SMTP server. However when I test the same code on my work computer, it is much slower. (My work computer is much faster than my home computer.) So I think the only difference is it talks to company Exchange server. Anyone experienced similar issues?

-Home computer with ISP: `isConnected()` takes 10-100ms

-Work computer with Exchange: `isConnected()` takes 5s.

-If I use the static `Transport.send()` to send message (no need to test connection), it takes about 300ms on my work computer.

Here is the sample code:

```
public class TestMail {
    static Session session;
    static InternetAddress fromAddr;
    static InternetAddress[] toAddr;
    static int n = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        String to = "yourname@gmail.com";   //System.getProperty("user.name") + "@aaaa.com"
        String from = "yourname@gmail.com"; //System.getProperty("user.name") + "@aaaa.com"

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.optonline.net");
        // props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.aaaa.com");

        session = Session.getInstance(props);
        fromAddr = new InternetAddress(from);
        toAddr = new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(to) };

        Transport bus = session.getTransport("smtp");
        bus.connect();

        String body = "This is the body of the email.\n";

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {

            Message msg = createMessage(i + "th email", body);

            long stime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if (!bus.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Connecting ....");
                bus.connect();
            }
            long etime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long isConnectedTime = etime - stime;

            stime = etime;
            bus.sendMessage(msg, toAddr);
            // Transport.send(msg);
            etime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long sendTime = etime - stime;

            System.out.printf("IsConnected: %d,  Sending: %d\n", isConnectedTime, sendTime);
        }

        bus.close();
    }

    public static Message createMessage(String subject, String body)
            throws MessagingException {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(fromAddr);
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddr);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(body);
        msg.saveChanges();
        return msg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Were you able to get the exchange send sped up?  I have noticed recently that send() is much faster than sendMessage through our Exchange server but not sure if it is networking or software (ours or Exchange's).

Answer (score 2):

You can, of course, use sendMessage without calling isConnected first.  I have no idea why it would be so much slower with Exchange.  The isConnected method just sends a NOOP command to the server to make sure the server is still there.  The server may be purposely delaying its response to the NOOP command to prevent abuse.